# Coloring Jenkins Output Console

Tags: jenkins, jestjs

I am finding a way for coloring my Jenkins output console like this image.
Do you know how I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a Plugin like [Jenkins ANSI Color Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansicolor/)

Comment: I have tried to use AnsiColor, but apparently, it just defines I static color for children inside his wrapping, I need a way that checks if the test passed and the color Green, if failed, red color.

Comment: Perhaps you can check for the status of your tests and conditionally add the color.